# PHPStorm & Less: как компилировать минимизированный файл с помощью File Watchers?

Tags: phpstorm, less, jetbrains

Каждый раз сталкиваюсь с этим вопросом и с долго ищу ответ англоязычном stackOverflow.

В PHPStorm нужно компилировать "на лету" минимизированный .css файл из .less. 
File Watcher настроен, файл компилируется исправно, но какой флаг нужно добавить к аргументам, чтобы получить **минимизированный** файл?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Введение

**Представленный в этой части код не является ответом!**

Безуспешно попытавшись найти ответ на свой вопрос (вероятно, плохо искал), я решил поступить так, как следовало сделать с самого начала - заглянуть в help node-модуля less. Выполнив команду, я получил исчерпывающий ответ -

```
-x, --compress           Compresses output by removing some whitespaces.
```

Вот оно! - подумал я, добавил флаг --compress в настройках File Watcher и получил... минимизированный файл с предупреждением

```
The compress option has been deprecated. We recommend you use a dedicated css minifier, 
for instance see less-plugin-clean-css.html
```

Дальше я проследовал на страницу https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css, где нашел итоговую, рабочую инструкцию.

### Рабочий ответ

Требуется установить дополнительно модуль less-plugin-clean-css командой

```
npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
```

и затем к аргументам Watcher'а добавить

```
--clean-css="--s1 --advanced --compatibility=ie8"
```

в итоге настройки Watcher'a в моем случае выглядели вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл получаем минимизированный, но с сохраненными комментариями. Описание всех аргументов модуля clean-css можно найти на странице https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css. 
Там я нашел ответ, **как при минимизации убрать комментарии**:

требуется к аргументам для --clean-css добавить флаг --s0 (в моем случае - исправить уже имеющийся флаг --s1) таким образом:

```
 --clean-css="--s0 --advanced --compatibility=ie8"
```